# Помогите сделать скрипт, чтобы найти в select'e значение по value в option

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблемку в проекте. Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку Choose в select'e выбралось значение, которое ввел в input. Но не по значению option, а по значению value в этом option.
Вот код примерно похожий:

```html
<select id="user_id" class="js-select" placeholder="Выберите уголь" required name="km" onchange="update(event.target, 'b1')" class="">
  <option value="один">1</option>
  <option value="два">2</option>
  <option value="три">3</option>
</select>

<input id="inp">

<input type="button" value="choose"
  onclick="a=document.getElementById('user_id');b=document.getElementById('inp');for(i=1;i<a.options.length; i++) {if (a.options[i].innerHTML==b.value) {a.options[i].selected=true; return}}"
>
```

Comment: Что такое `a`? Где именно вы объявили её с помощью `let` или `const`? То же самое с `b` и `i`.

Comment: Я плохо знаю js, но этот код работает, только он делает поиск по `option`, но не по `value` этого `option`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function selectByValue() {
    const selectElement = document.getElementById('user_id');
    const inputValue = document.getElementById('inp').value;

    for (let i = 0; i < selectElement.options.length; i++) {
        if (selectElement.options[i].value === inputValue) {
            selectElement.options[i].selected = true;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<select id="user_id" class="js-select" placeholder="Выберите уголь" required name="km" >
    <option value="один">1</option>
    <option value="два">2</option>
    <option value="три">3</option>
</select>

<input id="inp">

<input type="button" value="choose" onclick="selectByValue()">
```

Этот код сравнивает значение, введенное в поле input, с атрибутом value каждой опции в select, и устанавливает выбранную опцию с соответствующим значением value.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вы просто супер!!! Этого я и хотел=))

Comment: Рад был помочь!)))